# Describing the following code

Tags: c

I've got a question regarding an assignment i've been given.

-There are two integeras, `a` and `b`, which has the value of -1 and 1 respectively.
 What's the value of `a` and `b` after running the following code and WHY.

```
 if(!++a)

   b+=a++;
```

When i run this code i'm getting the values 1 and 1. I can not really figure out WHY though... Im getting quite confused over the if statement, could anyone explain this for a beginner trying to learn C?

Comment: @Vladp "**When i run this code**"...

Comment: Also, @OP: get yourself a good C book. The answer is really trivial. `!` is a logical NOT operator, and `++a` and `a++` both decrement the value of `a`, yielding the already incremented and the original (not-yet-incremented) values, respectively.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks even a minimal understanding of the language being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!++a)
```

First of all, `if (a)` is identical to `if (a != 0)`. Weird, but true. Zero means false, any other number means true.

Saying `if (!a)` inverts that meaning.

`++a` increments `a` and returns the new value. (Unlike `a++`, which increments `a` but returns the old value, not the new one.)

Putting all that together, this says "increment `a` and test whether the answer is zero". If `a = -1`, then this is indeed true.

Usually people would write `if (...) {do stuff}`, but if the "do stuff" part is only one statement, you can leave out the brackets. We've already established that the condition is true in this case, so the "b+=a++" line is run.

If we put some spaces on that, we have

```
b += (a++);
```

So, increment `a` again, but before that, add it's (old) value to `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to this one:

```
int a = -1;
int b = 1;

a += 1;
if (a == 0) {
    b += a;
    a += 1;
}
```

You should see why both variables end up as 1 here. Now try to figure out why these codes are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`++a` gives you the value after increment, so you get `0` which means false. The `!` operator makes it `true`.

Then you basically have

```
b = b + a;
a++;
```

So `b` remains `1` and `a` gets another increment and ends up at `1` too.

The main concept here is the difference between `a++` and `++a`. If you use `a++` you will first get the value of `a` and then the value is incremented whereas for `++a` the value is first incremented and then returned.

Answer (score 0):

Initially a= -1 when your code will enter if (!++a) and it is pre increment  first increment of a will happen so a will become 0 and !0 is 1 and it will enter in the if block.

now b+=a++;
here a++ is post increment so you can devide this statement in two parts.

first  b+=a; b+=0 so b will remain 1.

second       a++; a will become 1.